# PHP and AJAX: AJAX is working, PHP is not implementing query

Tags: php, ajax, forms, file, mysqli

Slowly but surely, I'm going to get AJAX.  I've got a form that uploads a text field and a file to a database.  I had the query working in PHP earlier, but not the AJAX.  Now the AJAX is working but not the PHP.  And I know that some will find it objectionable to load an image to a BLOB, but the query itself works, so I'd like to focus on the problems I'm having getting my javascript to talk to my PHP.  I've researched the issue like crazy and tried a lot of things, but the thing I've come away with is that uploading files is complex.

Questions
1.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but if javascript and jquery implement a "POST" call, the passed parameters shouldn't show up in the page's URL? Because they are.
2.  Why is my PHP file not parsing out the sent data and sending it on to the database?  I can see in the URL and in Firebug (although I'm slowly learning Firebug as well) that data is being passed.  I ran a test php file and I am connecting with the database with that file.

Thanks!

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.form.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#addForm').validate();
            function addRecord() {
                $("#aTable").hide('slow', function () { //this is not working
                    alert('Working on it.');
                });
                $("#tableText").hide('slow', function() {//this is not working
                        alert('Working on it.');
                });
                var output = document.getElementById("message");
                var nAname = document.getElementById("aname");
                var nAInfo = new FormData(document.forms.namedItem("addForm"));
                nAInfo.append('aname', nAname);

               $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "addPhoto.php",
                data: nAInfo
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="addForm" name="addForm" onsubmit="addRecord()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>Name: </label>
    <input type="text" id="aname" name="aname" class=required/>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Photo: </label>
    <input type="file" id="aimage"  name="aimage" class="required">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="ADD" />
    <br>
</form>

<div id="message" name="message"></div>
<br>
<br>
<div id="image_display"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $db->connect_errno . ") " . $db->connect_error;
}

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

        echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

    $aname = $_POST['aname'];
    $errorinfo = $_FILES["aimage"]["error"];
    $filename = $_FILES["aimage"]["name"];
    $tmpfile = $_FILES["aimage"]["tmp_name"];
    $filesize = $_FILES["aimage"]["size"];
    $filetype = $_FILES["aimage"]["type"];

    $fp = fopen($tmpfile, 'r');
    $imgContent = fread($fp, filesize($tmpfile));
    fclose($fp);

    if (!($filetype == "image/jpeg" && $filesize > 0)) {
        echo "Import of photo failed";
    }

    if ($filetype == "image/jpeg" && $filesize > 0 && $filesize < 1048576) {

        if (!($stmt=$mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO actor_info (aname, aimage_data) VALUES (?,?)"))) {
            echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ")" . $mysqli->error;
        }

        if (!$stmt->bind_param("ss", $aname, $imgContent)) {
            echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno .") " . $stmt->error;
        }

        if (!$stmt->execute()) {
            echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
        }
    $stmt->close();
    }
    else {
        echo "Image must be under 1 MB";
    }

echo mysqli_error();
mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

Comment: stop. step back from this code. look at how crazy it is. you're using jquery... but implementing your **OWN** ajax code? **WHY**? jquery has wonderful and SIMPLE ajax interfaces built into it: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: As well, if your form parameters are showing up in the url, then you're probably not doing a POST, it's most likely a GET. You can trivially debug this by doing `echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` in your php code. Your file handling code is attrocious. `addslashes()` is so crappy it can't even HOPE to aspire to being called atrocious. **NEVER** use it, especially in database code. **NEVER* assume a file upload has succeeded. **NEVER** trust data in $_FILES

Comment: @Marc B I've tried the following without success $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "addActorPhoto.php",
                    data: nAInfo
                });

Comment: @Marc B  I placed `echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` under the mysqli connection code and before the implementation of the file parsing but did not receive a message back.  Not sure if this is because of the way I'm sending code or because the PHP file isn't going anywhere.  Any suggestions for where to go next?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#aTable").hide('slow', function () { //this is not working
           alert('Working on it.');
});

$("#tableText").hide('slow', function() {//this is not working
           alert('Working on it.');
});
```

The above code is not working because you don't have any elements with id '#aTable' or '#tableText' in your html code.

Try print_r($_POST) to see whether all the values get to server or not.

Also using JQuery's Ajax function will make your code easier...below is a sample

```
$.ajax({
        url : $domain + "/index/email/" + "?" + $arguments, //add your args here...
        cache : false,
        beforeSend : function (){
            alert('sending....');
        },
        complete : function($response, $status){
            if ($status != "error" && $status != "timeout") {
                if($response.responseText == "200"){
        alert('done');
                } else {
        alert($response.responseText);
                }
            }
        },
        error : function ($responseObj){
            alert("Something went wrong while processing your request.\n\nError => "
                + $responseObj.responseText);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Forgive my newbieness, but is `$status` something I have to define or is that the response of the server and nothing further needs to be done? And is response functioning as the variable that plants the returned message in a designated location, i.e. `var response=document.getElementById("message");`?

Comment: There are elements with those id's in my code, but in the interests of being concise I didn't post them.

Comment: you don't have to define $status it is returned automatically. Also the response will be returned in the $response object so you can simply referred to response as $response.responseText and load it into your div like this $('#message').html($response.responseText);

Comment: Also if you don't want to reinvent the wheel you can try some of the shelf plugins which also gives additional functionality..I.e. http://www.uploadify.com/demos/